# Is there any way add a html-wrapper to field in Django admin form?

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I want to add to the HTML-wrapper for the text-field to correctly display fields' styles in the TinyMCE editor. Is there any way to do this?

P.S. [readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) and **property**, as I understand it, for display only.